# Pressed button layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, layout, frontend

i'm working in an Android application and i having some troubles with the layout, i'm newbie in Android layout.

I need to create this button:

[image]

But i'm having trouble with this black shadow inside the button.

Someone?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh wait I think I misunderstood, so you want it to only change the text while it is being continually pressed?

Comment: Sorry for my question, it's not clear, i edited the post, so i want to make this black "shadow" inside of my button to look like a pressed button.

Comment: Take a look on http://android-holo-colors.com/. It will generate all necessary nine patch assets plus associated XML drawables and styles which you can copy straight into your project

Answer (score 1):

I see then for this you actually have to change the styling of the button.  Such as setting a background for the button and potentially removing current styling.

This is a styling I am currently using, doesn't look like how you want it but it might get you closer to your answer. This is a drawable I use.

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:angle="90" android:centerColor="@color/bonzi_blue" android:endColor="@color/bonzi_blue" android:startColor="@color/bonzi_blue" />

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />

    <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="6dp" />

    <corners android:radius="10px"/>
</shape></item>
<item><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:angle="90" android:centerColor="@color/bonzi_blue" android:endColor="@color/bonzi_blue" android:startColor="@color/bonzi_blue" />

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />

    <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="6dp" />

    <corners android:radius="10px"/>
</shape></item>
```